# How to deploy new ActiveX objects

Tags: deployment, browser, activex

I am supporting some classic ASP pages. One of the core 3rd party components had a leak and was fixed with a new version of their CAB. For first time users or the ones who deleted the objects, browser prompts and downloads the object. How can new cab be made available for existing users with limited privileges?

Comment: I take it you mean getting through their user/browser security?

Answer (score 0):

If their privileges don't include downloading/installing ActiveX, you will have to have a user with elevated permissions login and download the components.  We have our support center, login to the user's computer, and login into our website.  This downloads the components.

The only other option is to set up some sort of administrative deployment system, possibly packaging the objects for Windows "[Run Advertised Programs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb633225.aspx)" or something similar.